# How to fill the missing value in a particular range in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with 2 columns naming Row Lables and Average. Below is the table

[image]

As you can see there is no value 6 in the table. How to insert a row with value 6 and Average as null in excel? The output must be like below

[image]

Comment: You won't solve this with a formula, you need VBA.

Comment: Maybe `=LET(Indx,SEQUENCE(MAX($A$1:$A$8)), IndxList,"<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",FALSE,Indx)&"</s></t>", AvgList,"<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",FALSE,XLOOKUP(Indx,$A$1:$A$8,$B$1:$B$8,""))&"</s></t>", IFERROR(CHOOSE({1,2},FILTERXML(IndxList,"//s"),FILTERXML(AvgList,"//s")),""))`